# How do I go about accessing the text input from a textbox within a content template in my C# code behind file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, account, createuserwizard, contenttemplate

I have used a few variations of accessing the text from `StreetNbrtxt` including

```
1) Directly: Profile.StreetNbr = StreetNbrtxt.Text; (Didn't work)
2) Using FindControl: Profile.StreetNbr = ((TextBox)RegisterUserWizardStep.FindControl("StreetNbrtxt")).Text; ('Not a instantiated class' Error message)
```

Further, I have not been able to see the values that I added in the text boxes that were added to the pre-coded files that were in the Account folder in Visual Studio Express 2012.

The code I have from the Register.aspx is as follows:

```
    <asp:CreateUserWizard runat="server" ID="RegisterUser" ViewStateMode="Disabled" OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser" ActiveStepIndex="0">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="wizardStepPlaceholder" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="navigationPlaceholder" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server" ID="RegisterUserWizardStep">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <p class="message-info">
                    Passwords are required to be a minimum of <%: Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength %> characters in length.
                </p>

                <p class="validation-summary-errors">
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" />
                </p>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
                    <ol>
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
                        </p>
            :
            :
            :
            :
            :
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label ID="StreetNumberlbl" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="StreetNbrtxt">Street Number:</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="StreetNbrtxt" runat="server" CssClass="style11"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="StreetNbrtxt"
                                CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="A street address number is required" ToolTip="Please insert your home address number"
                                ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </p>    
                    </ol>               
        <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Register" />
         </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>
```

Any Idea of how I should access the Street Number from the user input textbox?

Answer (score 0):

`CreateUserWizard` Control is based on `Wizard` control, which has steps. So you need to find the control inside the step. In your case, it is in the first step. You can access the control like this.

```
TextBox StreetNbrtxt = 
(TextBox)RegisterUser.WizardSteps[0].
FindControl("CreateUserStepContainer").FindControl("StreetNbrtxt");
```

You can see how it works. I hope this works for you too, as it is working for me for a long time. Thanks!

**Edit:** Here is the link for more reading about wizard control at [official website](https://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/standard/wizard.aspx).